# Left-align radio button label combo vertically on separate lines with only CSS

Tags: css, forms, radio-button, vertical-alignment, fieldset

### The Issue

I have a group of radio buttons that are organized vertically, stacked. They are on separate lines by use of <br> tag. I want to align them vertically using CSS, left-aligned, 100 pixels from the left. It doesn't seem like it would be that hard, but I haven't got it figured out yet. Here's an illustration I made to clarify the desired result:

#### The default alignment:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                  * choice 1                                    |
|                  * choice 2 is a different length              |
|                  * choice 3 is also long                       |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### The desired left-aligned radio buttons with labels on right:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|        * choice 1                                              |
|        * choice 2 is a different length                        |
|        * choice 3 is also long                                 |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Made with [Asciiflow.com](http://asciiflow.com/)

### The code

Here is my code:

#### CSS & HTML

```css
form {
  background-color: #ffffb3;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 690px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}
label {
  margin-left: 100px;
  postion: absolute;
}
/*input[type="checkbox"]:checked + */
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="mailto:eric.hepperle@pcc.edu">

  <h2>Visitor Survey</h2>

  <fieldset>

    <label for="myName">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName">
    <br>

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br>

  </fieldset>

  <p>What is your favorite movie?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="transformers" value="Transformers!">
  <label for="transformers">Transformers!</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="dark-knight" value="Dark Knight">
  <label for="dark-knight">Dark Knight</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="goodwillhunting" value="Good Will Hunting">
  <label for="goodwillhunting">Good Will Hunting</label>

  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Query">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

### What I've Tried Already

- Searched the web and Stack Overflow but the results weren't exactly applicable.
- I've tried floating both button and label left, margin-left: 100px, position absolute, but it doesn't work.
- I've tried messing with `input[type="radio"] + label` (but I need the label to come first), to no avail.
- Wrapping the radio buttons and labels in a fieldset.

### My Questions

So, I have several questions:

1. How to do this elegantly with CSS **without using divs or fieldsets**? Or, in other words, can this be done with plain CSS with just the label and input[type="radio"] selectors?
2. I understand that fieldsets are for accessibility, but I'm wondering is it best practice to use fieldsets, or are they a technique that is growing obsolete?
3. Can I align the radios and their labels in separate lines vertically without using the <br> tag?

Comment: Well formatted and good quality of question. I'm also checking your queries. :)

Comment: @SayedRafeeq thanks. I'm looking forward to your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

1. Stack the `radio` button and `label` combo using pseudo elements (`:after` in this case). No need of `<br>`.
2. Apply `margin-left` to `input[type="radio"]` instead of `label`.

Using `:after` I have created a empty block (`display: block;`). This empty block is placed at the end of `label` so it pushes the next element to a new line.

**Note:**

For explanation, I have highlighted the **empty block**(*created by* `:after`) with a red border. Remove if necessary.

```css
form {
  background-color: #ffffb3;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 690px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}
label {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /* Below code(border: 1px solid red;) is just for illustration, remove if necessary */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/*input[type="checkbox"]:checked + */
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="mailto:eric.hepperle@pcc.edu">

  <h2>Visitor Survey</h2>

  <fieldset>

    <label for="myName">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName">
    <br>

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br>

  </fieldset>

  <p>What is your favorite movie?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="transformers" value="Transformers!">
  <label for="transformers">Transformers!</label>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="dark-knight" value="Dark Knight">
  <label for="dark-knight">Dark Knight</label>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" id="goodwillhunting" value="Good Will Hunting">
  <label for="goodwillhunting">Good Will Hunting</label>

  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Query">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Comment: I think this might be it. Let me try to implement and I'll report back. If it works I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @CodeSlayer2010 : Happy to help!

Comment: It works! I've marked your answer as correct. One question though. I just read W3Schools take on "::before" and "::after" pseudo-elements, but didn't see anything to explain how you are using it. I can use them with "content" property to put stuff before/after just fine. Can you explain what `label:after` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should wrap form groups with divs.
I know you said not to use them, but that's the most elegant and simple way. Going any other way is just not as good.

This will allow you to get rid of the `br` because naturally, `div` is defined as `display: block` in CSS which means it will be on separate lines.

To do what you want, you should just align those divs to the left, and add a 100px `padding-left` to each div.

Not sure about best practices but I haven't heard that you actually need fieldsets and I got along just fine in terms of accessibility without them.

Comment: The OP doesn't want `div`s

Comment: I addressed that. There isn't any reason NOT to use them. They are there for a reason. It's like wanting to screw a screw without a screwdriver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accepted @Pugazh's answer because it was more correct for what I was seeking and included working code.